# Блокирование PDB-файлов в Visual Studio и как этого избежать

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Ситуация следующая: 
Для Visual Studio 2015 разрабатывается VSIX плагин.
Я создаю в Visual Studio произвольный проект, например, dll.
После билда проекта он должен загрузиться во vsix package c помощью следующих строк:

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes('fileName.dll');
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(bytes);
```

Далее я начинаю исследовать сборку с помощью рефлексии.
Проблема в следующем - если отредактировать код произвольного проекта и попробовать повторно сделать билд проекта, то возникает следующая ошибка: 'Cannot open 'filename.pdb' for writing -- 'The process cannot access the file 'filename.pdb' because it is being used by another process.'

Соответственно, в окне Modules видно загруженные символы для 'filename.dll'
Непонятно почему загружаются символы в Visual Studio и как этого избежать?
В принципе можно было бы создать домен и загружать dll в него (а затем выгружать), однако это связано с ограничениями загрузки библиотек (проблема может возникнуть если библиотека имеет референсы на другие dll - в этом случае файлы библиотек нужно копировать в каталог приложения + могут возникнуть проблемы взаимодействия между доменами).
Воспроизвести эту проблему можно следующим способом:

1) создаем Vsix package

2) добавляем дефолтовый ToolWindow, где в метод, который подписан на событие дефолтовой кнопки добавляем строки кода, который я привел, предварительно прописав путь к файлу который будет скомпилирован (4)

3) запускаем эксперементальный инстанс (или просто устанавливаем скомпилированный пакадж)

4) создаем проект с dll (путь к выходному файлу должен быть прописан в (2)) и добавляем там произвольный метод

5) если после нажатия на кнопку (2) попробовать модифицировать исходный код dll и попробовать сбилдить проект заново, то это уже не получиться сделать